# Database design to assign specific tags to an item

Tags: mysql, database-design, tags

I am trying to build a little system that would assign specific tags to an item, or a person to be precise. So, I have a list of persons and a list of tags. I need to assign 3 specific tags to each person (that correspond to 3 different skills this person might have).

In a nutshell, the output would look like this :

```
Person 1 | webdesign, ux, jquery
Person 2 | blogging, photography, wordpress
Person 3 | graphic-design, 3d, inventor
...
```

For now, those lists are stored in two different tables :

```
persons
-------
person_id
person_name

tags
-------
tag_id
tag_name
```

My main goal is to avoid repetition and to simply assign 3 existing tags to an existing person.

Could you give me a few hints on how to implement this? I know that a [three-table](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) design is common for a tagging system, but is it relevant in my situation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure that you don't have any duplicates and to be able to add `N` tags to a person, then to properly implement a normalized design you would need a third table to link the `tags` to each `person`

```
persons_2_tags
--------------
person_id
tag_id
```

To guarantee uniqueness, you can either use a composite primary key, or add a `unique index` to the table including both columns.

See an example of the above in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01633).

If you need to enforce the 3 tag limit at the database level, you can add a third column to the `persons_2_tags` table (`tag_number` for example) that is an `enum` with values of `1, 2, 3` and add that to your `unique index`. Insert logic would need to be handled at the application level, but would be enforced by the `index`.

Comment: Exactly.  And to get the uniqueness, you'd add a unique constraint on the combination of the person_id and tag_id columns.

Comment: Oops, lost my train of thought... I would actually use a combo primary key.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much what I had in mind. Could you show me a typical request that would allow me to exploit those 3 tables in order to do what I described?

Answer (score 1):

Do your requirements specify "exactly" 3 tags?

The third table is recommended to stay normalized. It's a typical Many-to-many relationship. This offeres the greatest amount of flexibility since you can have an unlimited, yet unique list of user/tag pairs.

You could have 3 columns in the user table for each tag. Performance would be improved at the expense of flexibility. Queries like, "List all the users with tag = 'X'" are a little harder. There may be several null values if you allow fewer than 3 tags. Of course in this setup, you'll have to create a new column and a lot of code to expand beyond three columns.

Comment: There is indeed a constraint, each person will necessarily have 3 tags assigned.

Answer (score 0):

*I think that I would probably do the three table design which Jeff O mentioned, however, just to present an alternative view...*

If you're just talking about tags, that is, a short string with no other meta data, I don't know that you'd *need* a `tags` table. Essentially, the tag itself could be the its id.

```
persons (person_id, person_name);
tags (person_id, tag);
```

Yeah, you'd get a bit of repetition there, but they're short strings anyway and it should really make a difference.